# Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/email'

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I get this error when running my meteor application with the command "meteor"

```
W20171125-19:06:27.907(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\connect\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
W20171125-19:06:28.704(2)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20171125-19:06:28.705(2)? (STDERR)                                             ^
W20171125-19:06:28.706(2)? (STDERR)
W20171125-19:06:28.706(2)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/email'
W20171125-19:06:28.707(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
W20171125-19:06:28.707(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
W20171125-19:06:28.707(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (C:\Users\connect\Desktop\hello_world\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:287:32)
W20171125-19:06:28.708(2)? (STDERR)     at makeInstallerOptions.fallback (packages\modules-runtime.js:651:18)
W20171125-19:06:28.708(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:244:16)
W20171125-19:06:28.708(2)? (STDERR)     at notifications.js (lib/collections/notifications.js:1:24)
W20171125-19:06:28.709(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20171125-19:06:28.709(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20171125-19:06:28.710(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\connect\Desktop\hello_world\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\app.js:584:1
W20171125-19:06:28.710(2)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (C:\Users\connect\Desktop\hello_world\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:414:13)
```

and when I run "meteor npm install meteor/email"
I get the following error

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/meteor/email.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\connect\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-25T17_24_15_075Z-debug.log
```

any help, please !

Comment: Try `meteor add email` instead of `meteor npm install meteor/email`

Comment: @MichelFloyd thank you , it worked just fine ,  still I got another error :'D